# Define scope for Excel solver

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have two sheets, one with RTD/volatile data and the other with some formulas that depend on the first. I would like to run the solver on the second sheet without refreshing the first. That should amount to instruct the solver to do `Sheet.Calculate` rather than `Calculate`. Is this possible? I would like to avoid writing my own solver

Comment: Use the worksheet calculate event?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How do I incorporate that in the solver?

Comment: I probably would make a static copy of the first sheet (copy values) and base the optimization on that one.